# What websocket package for nodejs to connect with libwebsocket in C?

Tags: objective-c, node.js, websocket

Hi i am having some problem to create a nodejs websocket server to communicate with client using libwebsocket?.What package for node js to connect with that libwebsocket client
Thanks

```
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
    var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});
    console.log('SERVER LISTEN ON PORT 8080');

    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
      console.log(ws);
    });
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet you wrote, or the links you are refering. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just added it.. the one i am using right now is ws but when my client try to connect there is no log message.